# Using variable from one class in another class

Tags: swift

I have two classes: `CollectionCell` and `ViewController`.

The first class is used for Collection View Cell (in which I have placed a button). In `CollectionCell` class I need to connect outlet for this button: `@IBOutlet weak var firstPercent: UIButton!`.

In `ViewController` class  I need to use var of this button: `firstPercent`.

How can I do that? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In `collectionViewDelegate`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Now declare your Custom Cell instance and then

you can use `CollectionCell.firstPercent` addTarget in ViewController and set this or
do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it something like below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ZonesCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ZonesCell

    let keyValue = self.dataList[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
    cell.lblZoneName.text = keyValue[Keys.name] as? String

    if(keyValue[Keys.status] as? Bool)! {
        cell.lblZoneName.textColor  = UIColor.white
    } else {
        cell.lblZoneName.textColor = UIColor.red
    }
    return cell
}
```

There lets suppose ZonesCell is the collectionCell contains lblZoneName as label.
You can use button same as label.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate for this.

Add a protocol named  “CollectionCellDelegate“ for your cell and add a delegate method for your button action. Pass cell itself as a parameter to that method. Conform to “CollectionCellDelegate“ from your ViewController and implement delegate method inside ViewController. Finally but most important step, assign your view controller as CollectionCellDelegate from cellForItemAt method.

```
protocol CollectionCellDelegate : class {
    func didPressButtonFirstPercent(_ cell: CollectionCell)
}

//Inside your CollectionCell class declare a variable to hold your cell delegate

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    //Add a variable to hold your delegate
    weak var delegate: CollectionCellDelegate?

    //Outlet for your button
    @IBOutlet weak var firstPercent: UIButton!

    //Action for your button
    @IBAction func didPressButtonFirstPercent(_ sender: Any) {
         delegate?.didPressButtonFirstPercent(self)
    }
}

//ViewController Conform to CollectionCellDelegate

class ViewController: UIViewController, CollectionCellDelegate{


     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: “Cell_Identifier”, for: indexPath) as!                           CollectionCell

        //Set ViewController as your CollectionCell delegate
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
     }

    //Implement delegate method here

    func didPressButtonFirstPercent(_ cell: CollectionCell) {

        //You can access your button here like below
        Let firstPercent =  cell.firstPercent

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{


     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionCell

        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell. firstPercent.tag = indexPath.row
 example project

        return cell
    }
}
```